# Dynamic class based on data attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a collection of cards which are iterated. Every card has a color attribute and I want to use this as part of the class of a div to give it a dynamic background. The current code is:

```
      <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
        <div class="bg-red-600">{{ card.category | uppercase }}</div>
        <div>{{ card.title }}</div>
      </div>
```

In this case, in the value `bg-red-600`, `red` should be replaced with `card.color`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options.
In template:

```
  <div :class="`bg-${card.color}-600`">{{ card.category | uppercase }}</div>
```

Via separate method:

```
methods: {
  colorMethod(color) {
    return `bg-${color}-600`;
  },
},

<div :class="colorMethod(card.color)">{{ card.category | uppercase }}</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @John Nice to hear!